# How to get dataset column value from objectdatasource

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, detailsview

It has been so long since I've worked with webforms I've forgot how to gain access to the underlying data to get the column value so that I can set the current request for a specific product to the page title.

I've got a detailsview on a webforms page and I need to get the value of a column named Title.

How should I go about doing this?

I'm sure it is because I'm in the Page_Load event.

Any suggestions?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = GetDS(this.ObjectDataSourceItem);
    if (ds != null)
    {
        string title = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Title"].ToString();
        this.Page.Title = title;
    }
}
private DataSet GetDS(ObjectDataSource ods)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataView dv = (DataView)ods.Select();
    if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

My error is Invalid cast exception.

Here is a snapshot of my error:
[image: InvalidCastException]

---

The correct way to gain access to the underlying object, my custom object name Item.

```
   private Item GetItem(ObjectDataSource ods)
{
    Item itm = null;
    object[] iObjs = (object[])ods.Select();

    for (int i = 0; i < iObjs.Length; i++)
    {
        itm = (Item)iObjs[i];
    }
    return itm;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.select.aspx):
`ObjectDataSource.Select` doesn't have to return a `DataView` type. From the method signature, it returns an `IEnumerable`. From your debugger screenshot, you can see that it is an array of objects. You just need to iterate over the array to get to the value buried underneath.

Comment: Could you be so kind and offer us a little piece of code?

Comment: To do that, I will need to know what specific types are present in the object array. To start with, you could try this in Page_Load:

`var data = this.ObjectDataSourceItem.Select();
var type = data[0].GetType();
`
What do you find in the type?

Comment: I see what you're doing, that is the way I finally got the answer. With your help I was able to finally get it, but yea, the GetType() is a slick way to get the type.